# Receiving value from an intent (Bundle) in a non activity class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have two classes.  A is a non-activity class, and B is an activity.

In Class A, I have declared

```
Intent intent = new Intent(xxxx.context, PDFRenderer.class);         
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("file", filePath);
intent.putExtras(b);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
xxxxx.context.startActivity(intent);
```

Then in Class B, i've put in a method that returns a boolean.  I've put this in the `OnCreate()` method.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ama = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    manager = getPackageManager();
    RenderPeeDeeEff(getIntent().getStringExtra("file"));

    i = new Intent(this, RenderPdf.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putBoolean("returnValue", pdfCrashed);
    b.putString("pdfResult", pdfresult);
    i.putExtras(b);

    this.finish();
}
```

How do I pass the value of Bundle b back into class A even though I cannot use `getIntent()` since it's not an activity?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I prefer to use `SharedPreference` :)

Comment: i can't use the SharedPreference in a non-activity class? For example  SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(.... etc

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just have a method in class A such as `setBundle(Bundle bundle)` that you pass the bundle into? It really depends on the relationship that A and B have.

Comment: The non activity class calls the Activity class, then my app goes back to the non activity class. I'm trying to pass a value from the A. class back to the non A. class

Answer (score 0):

Somebody suggested SharedPreference, which might be good but the problem is your ClassA is not notified about the change made (assuming your ClassB is sort of Dialog). There are alternatives, such as registering a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) in your ClassA, and in ClassB:

```
i = new Intent(this, ACTION_CLASSB_FINISH);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putBoolean("returnValue", pdfCrashed);
b.putString("pdfResult", pdfresult);
i.putExtras(b);
this.sendBroadcast(i);
```

If you want to go for SharedPreference, you can register a [Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) to listen to a change in the returnValue too. Notice both of the case you still need to have the Context in ClassA in order to register and also unregister if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a overload Constructor in your Class A, which accepts a Bundle, using that you can retrieve your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult.

In the Activity whose context you're using to call startActivityForResult, implement onActivityResult.

In onActivityResult, pass the Bundle from the returned Intent to A